# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first

Tags: android, crash

Seeing this a lot, but no luck until I read [Take Control of Your Firebase Init on Android](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on.html)

So when I add the block of code mentioned, my app doesn't continuously crash when I click Login or Register.

Doesn't crash when added to  RegistrationActivity.java

```
FirebaseOptions.Builder builder = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
   .setApplicationId("1:0123456789012:android:0123456789abcdef")
   .setApiKey("your_api_key")
   .setDatabaseUrl("https://your-app.firebaseio.com")
   .setStorageBucket("your-app.appspot.com");
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, builder.build());
```

I can't login after entering my Firebase user, but that is because I never filled in my Firebase values from the example ones given to my DB values.  But I'm confused why my app doesn't crash immediately with this block of code to my RegistrationActivity.Java, but when I comment it out, I get the error mentioned in the title.

Could someone explain how I can get my original code to work without the block of code above, or is this the new way?  My issues all began when I started messing with my Gradle files so this is where I am today.  TIA.

Here is my Project Gradle

```
buildscript {

ext.versions = [
        'compileSdk'    : 27,
        'targetSdk'     : 27,
        'buildTools'    : '27.0.3',
//            'butterknife'   : '8.8.1',
//            'glide'         : '4.6.1',
//            'kotlin'        : '1.2.21',
//            'retrofit'      : '2.3.0',
//            'supportLibrary': '27.0.2'
]

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.5.4'
    //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }// Google's Maven repository
    }
}
}
```

Here is my Module App Gradle
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion versions.compileSdk
buildToolsVersion versions.buildTools

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.tinder"
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    customDebug {
        debuggable true
    }
}

}

repositories {
google()
jcenter()
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
implementation 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

}
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is my RegistrationActivity.java
    package com.example.tinder;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button mRegister;
private EditText mEmail, mPassword, mName;
private RadioGroup mRadioGroup;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthStateListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

//
//        FirebaseOptions.Builder builder = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
//                            

 //  .setApplicationId("1:0123456789012:android:0123456789abcdef")
//                .setApiKey("your_api_key")
//                .setDatabaseUrl("https://your-app.firebaseio.com")
//                .setStorageBucket("your-app.appspot.com");
//        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, builder.build());

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            final FirebaseUser user =     
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, 
MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }
    };

    mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

    mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);


    mRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int selectId = mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            final RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) 
findViewById(selectId);
            if(radioButton.getText() == null){
                return;
            }

            final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
            final String name = mName.getText().toString();
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, 
 password).addOnCompleteListener(RegistrationActivity.this, new 
 OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "sign up 
 error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                        DatabaseReference currentUserDb = 
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId);
                        Map userInfo = new HashMap<>();
                        userInfo.put("name" , name);
                        userInfo.put("gender", 
 "Male");//radioButton.getTag().toString());
                        userInfo.put("profileImageUrl", "default");
                        currentUserDb.updateChildren(userInfo);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthStateListener);

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthStateListener);
}
}
```

Here is my MainActivitiy.java

```
package com.example.tinder;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

   import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
    import com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private cards cards_data[];
private arrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
private int i;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private String currentUId;
private DatabaseReference usersDb;




ListView listView;
List<cards> rowItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    usersDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    checkUserPreferences();


    rowItems = new ArrayList<cards>();

    // al.add("javascript");
    // al.add("php");

    arrayAdapter = new arrayAdapter(this, R.layout.item, rowItems );
   // al.add("javascript");
   // arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer = (SwipeFlingAdapterView)     
findViewById(R.id.frame);

    flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    flingContainer.setFlingListener(new         

SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {
        @Override
        public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {
            // this is the simplest way to delete an object from the Adapter     
(/AdapterView)
            Log.d("LIST", "removed object!");
            rowItems.remove(0);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        @Override
        public void onLeftCardExit(Object dataObject) {
            //Do something on the left!
            //You also have access to the original object.
            //If you want to use it just cast it (String) dataObject


            cards obj = (cards) dataObject;
            String userId = obj.getUserId();

usersDb.child(userId).child("connections").child("pass").
child(currentUId).setValue(true);

            isConnectionMatch(userId);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Pass",     
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        @Override
        public void onRightCardExit(Object dataObject) {

            cards obj = (cards) dataObject;
            String userId = obj.getUserId();
            usersDb.child(userId).child("connections").child("meet").
child(currentUId).setValue(true);

            isConnectionMatch(userId);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Meet",     
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

        @Override
        public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int itemsInAdapter) {
            // Ask for more data here
            }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(float scrollProgressPercent) {
            }
        }
    );


    // Optionally add an OnItemClickListener
    flingContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new 
SwipeFlingAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(int itemPosition, Object dataObject) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Clicked", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    );
}

private void isConnectionMatch(String userId) {
    DatabaseReference currentUserConnectionsDb =     
usersDb.child(currentUId).child("connections").
child("meet").child(userId);
    currentUserConnectionsDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new 
ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "New Match", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                usersDb.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child("connections").
child("matches").child(currentUId).setValue(true);

usersDb.child(currentUId).child("connections").child("matches").
child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).setValue(true);
                }
            }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        }
    );
}


private String userGender;
private String searchGender;

public void checkUserPreferences(){
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference userDb = usersDb.child(user.getUid());
    userDb.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(user.getUid())){
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    if (dataSnapshot.child("gender") != null){
                        userGender =     
dataSnapshot.child("gender").getValue().toString();
                        searchGender = "Female";
                        switch (userGender) {
                            case "Male":
                                searchGender = "Female";
                                break;
                            case "Female":
                                searchGender = "Male";
                                break;
                        }
                        getSearchGender();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        }
    );
}





public void getSearchGender(){
    usersDb.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists() && 
!dataSnapshot.child("connections").child("pass").hasChild(currentUId) && 
!dataSnapshot.child("connections").child("meet").hasChild(currentUId) && 
dataSnapshot.child("gender").getValue().toString().equals(searchGender)) {
                String profileImageUrl = "default";
                if
 (dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue().equals("default")) {
                    profileImageUrl = 
dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue().toString();
                    }
                cards item = new cards(dataSnapshot.getKey(), 
dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString(), profileImageUrl);
                rowItems.add(item);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    }
    );
}

public void logoutUser(View view) {
    mAuth.signOut();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
ChooseLoginRegistrationActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    return;
    }

public void gotoSettings(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("userGender", userGender);
    startActivity(intent);
    return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using my original files from this post, the only changes needed were to uncomment 1 line and add back another (both in the Gradle files)

PROJECT APP uncommented the gms line and updated the version from original post

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.5.4'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
}
```

MODULE APP added to very bottom of file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I also had to update the google-service version to 3.2.0 from 3.0.1.  Nothing else was needed.  I'm now slightly ahead of my original issue was that my app crashes after updating (clicking CONFIRM button) on an uploaded photo.  The photo is stored in Firebase database storage, but I will troubleshoot this for a bit before asking for more help.  Thanks for the suggestions @VIKAS SHARMA

Answer (score 0):

You just need to initialise firebase in your app application file

just do this:

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                updateUI(user);
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateUI(null);
            }

            // ...
        }
    });
```

then let me know the loggs

Comment: Thanks.  That's what the error keeps telling me too :(

Comment: Thanks for elaborating.  I looked at 
...
[link](http://javasampleapproach.com/android/firebase-authentication-sign-up-sign-in-sign-out-verify-email-android) 
...
and then decided to uncomment my dependency in Project Gradle         **classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'** and used a newer version.  Re-added apply plugin: **'com.google.gms.google-services'**
back to my Module App Gradle  
...
...
Works now, but back to my original issue that had me mess all this up in the first place.  
...
Troubleshooting new upload errors, so slightly ahead of where I was a week ago lol

Comment: tell me the logs so that i can help you accordingly

Comment: I tried your code in LoginActivity.java since your code matched code there, but your code block gave an error of unknown updateUI message I couldn't figure out. My code worked before updating gradle dependency versions so I knew there couldn't be much code changes to resolve my problem.  Everyone else's solutions were creating too many modifications to make sense of for a newb like me.  Back to an upload error so I'll post a new thread if I can't figure out the new(ish) problem. **java.io.FileNotFoundException(/default (No such file or directory))** but uploads the file, then crashes